# Customizable Windows right-click file uploader?

Tags: windows, upload, ftp, content-management-system

I'm looking for a "right-click upload" application like [RightLoad](http://rightload.org/) - an application that can upload media files to a remote FTP server from the Windows Explorer's context menu. I want to customize the application to serve as a customized image uploading tool to a PHP-based CMS.

The user would upload images and other media files to a defined FTP account (I'm also very open for other methods of transport, as long as they are supported by run-off-the-mill web hosting stacks) that they could then use in the CMS they log in to.

For me to be able to do these customizations, the application would have to be Open Source - RightLoad is "only" Freeware. Alternatively, I'm open for closed-source and commercial suggestions as long as they allow "pre-packaged" server settings that can easily be deployed to the user.

Does anybody know such a tool compatible with at least the most current versions of Windows (XP, Vista, 7)?

> **Bounty**
>
> Thanks all for the great input. In the case at hand, I decided it's easiest for me to stick with RightLoad and create a workflow in which the URL presented by RightLoad after the upload is copy+pasted into the CMS. I am putting a bounty on this because I think it's a worthy question for future generations, and I want to be the first one to put up a 500 bounty under the new bounty system :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the send to menu using window's My network Places like this http://techie-buzz.com/how-to/right-click-and-send-to-ftp.html

Comment: I was going to suggest the same. Here is some more about creating network places http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308416/EN-US/ - I am pretty sure setting this up could easily be automated with VBScript too. And SO is the perfect place to ask.

Comment: I think it's so hard to use in a widely used application. It's just a solution for personal usages.

Answer (score 3):

I think [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/introduction) might have everything you want:

- [Open Source under GNU GPL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/license)
- [Windows Explorer's 'Send To' Context Menu](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration#send_to)
- [Drag 'n Drop Shell Extension](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/dragext)
- lots of additional features

and it can be scripted and is more secure than FTP due to using SSH

Comment: please, example of scripting. For example, I want to upload files from `/dir` to remove `/dir`, maintaining its subdirectories adequately.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on open source, why not create a [custom context menu handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144171%28VS.85%29.aspx) and send it using some open source FTP client?

I would have to check the details, if it's really viable, but I would start with it.

Comment: Good idea and thanks for the link, but I would like to be able to distribute a downloadable executable / MSI installer package that the user can download directly from the CMS (with pre-set account settings). I'm sure that can be scripted but it seems like an awful lot of work.

Comment: OK, so still looking for some ready solution. No luck so far. ;-)

Comment: I'm open to getting my hands dirty, but preferably, a ready made solution *would* be perfect :)

Comment: OK, here's what I found:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftpfileuploader/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/imageshaker/

http://uniupload.thecybershadow.net/


Looks like FTP FileUploader should do with minor modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I just had an idea, tested and working:

use regedit to edit HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/*/Shell
add a key in shell called FTP to Mysite, in the default value set it to FTP to Mysite.

then add a key to the FTP key you just created called command, in the command default value use:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe http://www.mysite.com?file=%1

what this will do is open IE and the address www.mysite.com?file=C:\path\to\file.jpg

now using $_GET you can get the file address, upload it via php to where ever, even add an interface...

now when the user right clicks on any file, they can upload it via your web site by clicking FTP

Comment: you of course could use any browser your client prefered, ie was just an example

Comment: I thought about it, but it's a completely different seperate answer. Both are viable

Comment: The option is there for a reason i presume... and what software? creating .reg files is easy enough. and the upload itself is handled on the serverside with something like php

Comment: well he could use something like http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Comment: No, he can't. What he wants to do is upload a file from a Windows machine to the server hosting the CMS. In order to use `ftp_put`, mysite.com would have to be a webserver on the Windows machine, otherwise it wouldn't be able to access the path you give it through the URL. That again is clumsy, because you could better trigger a PHP CLI script from the .reg instead of requiring a webserver and PHP on the Windows machine. Neither PHP nor a webserver are likely present on non-developer Windows. That's why I say he'd still need some software to do the actual upload.

Comment: A good solution would be to have the .reg call a simple batch script or vbscript or even just ftp.exe. All of these should be readily available on run-of-the-mill Windows.

Comment: You're right. I would have sworn there was a way to do it with just the file path using something like fput. There has got to be away... maybe flash? Oh well, Initially i tried just callling ftp.exe, using a script that help the commands, but I didnt see a way to use %1 to grab the specific filename the client right clicked.

Answer (score 0):

1) another software is [**RightLoad**](http://RightLoad.org) , i use it that this moment!

2) The nice software I used over years, was [**FLING**](http://www.nchsoftware.com/fling/). It adds **Right Click** menu in windows explorer... However, I have left the software, because till today (version 2.35) fling **DOESNT** support **SFTP** (And nowadays on all sites I use SFTP!!)

3) **I DONT like SEND-TO menu!** (because I think passwords saved in WINDOWS can be easily stolen by virus..)